# Template error when doing 3 levels deep of kendo grids (i.e. a detail grid for a detail grid of a main grid)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, master-detail

If I have a main Kendo cshtml view with a kendo grid that has a detail that is another grid which then has a detail that is another grid, an invalid template error occurs.  An example is shown below with the code not essential to the issue at hand replaced by '.......' for simplification purposes (it is not shown but the data source is sql using ajax).

File 1:  Index.cshtml

```
<div id="dvFileGroupSummaryGrid" style="width: auto;">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OverallSummary>()
          .Name("FileGroupSummaryGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
    .........
              }
          .AutoBind(true)
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("fileGroupFilesTemplate")
    .........
</div>
<script id="fileGroupFilesTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @Html.Partial("_FileGroupFilesSummary")
</script>'
```

File 2:  _FileGroupFilesSummary.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip_#=FileGroupID#")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("File Group Files Summary").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FileGroupSummary>()
                        .Name("FileGroupFilesSummaryGrid_#=FileGroupID#")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                ...........
                                })
                            ........
                            .AutoBind(true)
                            .ClientDetailTemplateId("fileResultsTemplate")
                            .ToClientTemplate()
                            )
                </text>
        );
    })
    .ToClientTemplate()
    )

<script id="fileResultsTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
   @Html.Partial("_FileResults")
</script>
```

File 3:  _FileResults.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip_#=MonitoredFileKey#")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("File Results").Content(@<text>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MonitoredFileResults>()
                .Name("MonitoredFileResultsGrid_#=MonitoredFileKey#")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                ...........
                })
             .........
            .AutoBind( true )
            .ToClientTemplate()
            )
        </text>
        );
    })
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem turned out to be that the partial view reference to the 3rd level detail grid had to be in the top level view (index.cshtml) instead of in the partial view that actually referenced it.  The code adjusted for this change is shown below.

File 1 Index.cshtml

```
<div id="dvFileGroupSummaryGrid" style="width: auto;">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OverallSummary>()
          .Name("FileGroupSummaryGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
    .........
              }
          .AutoBind(true)
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("fileGroupFilesTemplate")
    .........
</div>
<script id="fileGroupFilesTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @Html.Partial("_FileGroupFilesSummary")
</script>'
<script id="fileResultsTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
   @Html.Partial("_FileResults")
</script>
```

File 2 _FileGroupFilesSummary.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip_#=FileGroupID#")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("File Group Files Summary").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FileGroupSummary>()
                        .Name("FileGroupFilesSummaryGrid_#=FileGroupID#")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                ...........
                                })
                            ........
                            .AutoBind(true)
                            .ClientDetailTemplateId("fileResultsTemplate")
                            .ToClientTemplate()
                            )
                </text>
        );
    })
    .ToClientTemplate()
    )
```

File 3  _FileResults.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip_#=MonitoredFileKey#")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("File Results").Content(@<text>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MonitoredFileResults>()
                .Name("MonitoredFileResultsGrid_#=MonitoredFileKey#")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                ...........
                })
             .........
            .AutoBind( true )
            .ToClientTemplate()
            )
        </text>
        );
    })
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```